# find files in all subfolders and use them as input

Tags: command-line, find

I have a bunch of subfolders and each contains an input file `an_*` and an executable `run`. The command line for one execution in one subfolder is `./run <an_*`.

What I want to do is find all subfolders which contain an `an_*` file and execute `run` with `an_*` as input. My best bet was:
`find -name an_* -execdir ./run <'{}' \;` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just drop the input redirection `<`  on the find command line, the shell will try to redirect the input given to *find*. What you want is for the redirection to happen on the command executed by find. But `find` doesn't know how to do the redirection, so you have to ask it explicitly to run a shell to parse the command you give. Something like this:

```
find -name "an_*" -execdir sh -c "./run < {}" \;
```